# Dialpad for extension calling - Twilio

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api

How to do dialpad functionality in Twilio? I'm making outgoing calls from browser to phone numbers refering this [link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/php/client/outgoing-calls).

**TwiML Code :**

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml');

// put a phone number you've verified with Twilio to use as a caller ID number
$callerId = '+1xxxxxxxxx';

// put your default Twilio Client name here, for when a phone number isn't given
$number   = 'Name';

// get the phone number from the page request parameters, if given
if (isset($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber'])) {
    $number = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['PhoneNumber']);
}

// wrap the phone number or client name in the appropriate TwiML verb
// by checking if the number given has only digits and format symbols
if (preg_match("/^[\d\+\-\(\) ]+$/", $number)) {
    $numberOrClient = "<Number>" . $number . "</Number>";
} else {
    $numberOrClient = "<Client>" . $number . "</Client>";
}
?>
<Response>
    <Dial callerId="<?php echo $callerId ?>">
          <?php echo $numberOrClient ?>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

How can I add dialpad in my page so that user should be able to enter extention or menu options? Example: Click 1 to connect to sale manager.

Please help me if anyone knows about this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

Check out the [`sendDigits`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection#sendDigits) function in the Twilio Client for JavaScript SDK.  Calling this function tells the SDK to play DTMF tones.

```
function senddigits() {
  if (connection!=null) {
      connection.sendDigits("1");
  }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what a complete dynamic code would look like for Javascript SDK (Twilio Client).

```
 Twilio.Device.connect(function(connection) {

          //play DTMF tones
        if(connection!==null){
        $(document).on('click' ,'.numpad', function () {
        var number = $(this).val();
            connection.sendDigits(number);
        });
        }
});
```